# AzureB2C Authorization Code Flow with AspNet Core using Microsoft.Identity.Web does not return access or refresh tokens

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

It's a complicated business I know, however, I am a bit perplexed. I am trying to move my IdentityServer4 app authn/authz to Azure B2C and getting stuck. I am following the [guidance here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-app-with-api-options) to intercept the OnTicketReceived event so that I can augment the Principle with claims from the business domain. I have changed the ResponseType to include the  Authorization Code flow, i.e. "code id_token", but this is ignored and the response from the call does not include any other tokens other than the id_token.

From the samples given it would seem that access tokens are requested within controlller methods using the ITokenAcquisition API which is injected into the constructor. I can certainly refactor and get my app to work this way, but I am just wondering why the "Authorization code" flow is completely ignored even though I specify it in my Startup class.

Any ideas, or have I completely misunderstood how Microsoft.Identity.Web works?

[image]

When I inspect the OIDC message (see below) which is being sent to AAD B2C you can see it has scopes for "openid profile offline_access". Note that the message has ResponseType="code" and not "code id_token" which I have specifically requested.

[image]

Comment: What scopes are you asking for?

Comment: @ToreNestenius  Yes, of course - my code snapshot does not include any scopes. However, I tried adding scopes which are specific to my API app defined in Azure B2C and authorised for this client. Makes no difference. I also enabled "Access Tokens" and "ID Tokens" for Implicit Grant and Hybrid flows in AzureB2C for this app. When I inspect the request being made it only ever asks for "id_token". I can get an access token using  the ITokenAcquirer but just wonder why it is ignoring my request for "code id_token".

Comment: do you ask for the offline_access scope?

Comment: Hi @ToreNestenius - not specifically as I understand it is included automatically. However, I will try it later.  Thanks. J

Comment: I think you should verify which scopes that are actually requested.

Comment: Hi @ToreNestenius  - I have updated my question to include details of the OIDC request message. You can see the correct scopes but the ResponseType is simply "code".